# Discord.NET C# Bot exits the voice channel

Tags: c#, bots, discord.net, opus

The bot enters and immediately exits the voice channel. At the same time, if there is no one in the voice chat, then the bot will quietly remain there. If anything, I downloaded opus.dll and put it along with the exe file, and I don’t know what the problem is. Please help.

Error

```
20:54:58 App Command System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an invalid format. (0x8007000B)
   at Discord.Audio.OpusDecoder.CreateDecoder(Int32 Fs, Int32 channels, OpusError& error)
   at Discord.Audio.OpusDecoder..ctor()
   at Discord.Audio.Streams.OpusDecodeStream..ctor(AudioStream next)
   at Discord.Audio.AudioClient.CreateInputStreamAsync(UInt64 userId)
   at Discord.WebSocket.SocketGuild.RepopulateAudioStreamsAsync()
   at Discord.WebSocket.SocketGuild.FinishConnectAudio(String url, String token)
   at Discord.WebSocket.SocketGuild.ConnectAudioAsync(UInt64 channelId, Boolean selfDeaf, Boolean selfMute, Boolean external)
   at Discord.WebSocket.SocketGuild.ConnectAudioAsync(UInt64 channelId, Boolean selfDeaf, Boolean selfMute, Boolean external)
   at Discord.WebSocket.SocketVoiceChannel.ConnectAsync(Boolean selfDeaf, Boolean selfMute, Boolean external)
   at discord_bot.Modules.ExampleCommands.JoinChannel(IVoiceChannel channel) in C:\Users\hybas\source\repos\discord-bot\discord-bot\Modules\ExampleCommands.cs:line 58
   at Discord.Interactions.Builders.ModuleClassBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<<CreateCallback>g__ExecuteCallback|1>d.MoveNext()
```

I took the code for connecting to voice chat from the official Discord.NET documentation

```
[Command("join", RunMode = RunMode.Async)] 
public async Task JoinChannel(IVoiceChannel channel = null)
{
    // Get the audio channel
    channel = channel ?? (Context.User as IGuildUser)?.VoiceChannel;
    if (channel == null) { await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("User must be in a voice channel, or a voice channel must be passed as an argument."); return; }

    // For the next step with transmitting audio, you would want to pass this Audio Client in to a service.
    var audioClient = await channel.ConnectAsync();
}
```

Comment: What's at line 58 in ExampleCommands.cs?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just built the application and threw in the opus and libsodium library, and it worked